Anyway to migrate down in Drizzle
After generate and pushing migrations I see we have the option to drop migrations in the documentation. However this does nothing to the underlying db state. Running drizzle generate again also does not change it, how can we roll back or drop migrations with drizzle. What is the reccomended approach for this? Do I just need to manually go to the db and delete the tables and changes or is there any support drizzle provides in this.

Apparently rolling back a migration is a feature that is being worked on: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/discussions/1339#discussioncomment-9803758

try this to drop you'r migration file
npx drizzle-kit drop

or
migrations: {
    table: "migrations",
    schema: "public"
},

delete from the database migrations table where drizzle track migrations.
